# Most common element for pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset:

[image: Dataset]

The cuisine countries in it keep reoccurring and what I like to have as output is the list of let's say 5 food ingredients that are the most popular for every country.

The code until now:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter


filename="food.json"
food_dataset = pd.read_json(filename)

#getting seperate columns
country = food_dataset.loc[:,"country"]
ingredients = food_dataset.loc[:,"ingredients"]


Counter = Counter(ingredients) 

most_occur = Counter.most_common(3) 

print(most_occur)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for pandas 0.25+ [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and lambd function with first 5 index by created by counter by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
food_dataset = pd.DataFrame({'cuisine':['greek','southern_us'],
                             'ingredients':[list('andnsndnfndn'),
                                            list('ndnsndnfnsnd')]})
print (food_dataset)
       cuisine                           ingredients
0        greek  [a, n, d, n, s, n, d, n, f, n, d, n]
1  southern_us  [n, d, n, s, n, d, n, f, n, s, n, d]

N = 3
df = (food_dataset.explode("ingredients")
                  .groupby('cuisine')['ingredients']
                  .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[:N].tolist())
                  .reset_index())
print (df)
       cuisine ingredients
0        greek   [n, d, a]
1  southern_us   [n, d, s]
```

Alternative solution:

```
food_dataset['top'] = (food_dataset['ingredients']
                          .apply(lambda x: [y[0] for y in Counter(x).most_common(N)]))
print (food_dataset)
       cuisine                           ingredients        top
0        greek  [a, n, d, n, s, n, d, n, f, n, d, n]  [n, d, a]
1  southern_us  [n, d, n, s, n, d, n, f, n, s, n, d]  [n, d, s]



df = (food_dataset.explode("ingredients")
                  .groupby('cuisine')['ingredients']
                  .apply(lambda x: [y[0] for y in Counter(x).most_common(N)])
                  .reset_index())
print (df)
       cuisine ingredients
0        greek   [n, d, a]
1  southern_us   [n, d, s]
```

Solution if each values in `cousine` column are unique:

```
food_dataset['top'] = (food_dataset['ingredients']
                          .apply(lambda x: [y[0] for y in Counter(x).most_common(N)]))
print (food_dataset)
       cuisine                           ingredients        top
0        greek  [a, n, d, n, s, n, d, n, f, n, d, n]  [n, d, a]
1  southern_us  [n, d, n, s, n, d, n, f, n, s, n, d]  [n, d, s]
```